# Access static json file in google app engine 2.7 standard environment - IOError(2, 'No such file or directory')

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

We are trying to access .json file inside our python code in Google App Engine.

Here is our app.yaml

```
service: worker
instance_class: F2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 100
  min_pending_latency: 200ms  # default value
  max_pending_latency: automatic

handlers:

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /javascripts
  static_dir: javascripts

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|json))$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|json)$
  application_readable: true


- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  application_readable: true 

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico


- url: /.*
  script: worker.app
  login: admin

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

We are using it in our application like this.

```
 path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)[0], '/static/google_web_app_script_credentials.json')
 flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(path,self.GOOGLESHEETS_SCOPES )
```

But we are receiving the error.

```
IOError(2, 'No such file or directory')
```

We have tried various options of changing path including path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**)[0], '../static/google_web_app_script_credentials.json')

When we go to the GCP console -> Debug and review the current code we are able to see the .json file under static folder. This means that the file is there, we are not able to get the application to read it. This service is as "worker".

Answer (score 0):

From your App Engine app, you don't have access to your static files.  Move the file to another location within your project, and you will then be able to access it.

Even more importantly, you don't want to store credentials in your static folder!  Anyone on the web will be able to access them via the URL!

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by another location? Are you suggesting we create a sub-folder with a different name (other than Static)? How would this manifest in the app.yaml? How should we provide the path in the python code? What we currently have is not working. Do we need to make any changes to this - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|json))$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|json)$
  application_readable: true

Comment: You can store the files in a Storage bucket and use them as you wish. You got here some libraries that will help you manipulate the files - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries